# How does Hibernate keep track of Detached and Persistent object from different Sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, hibernate-mapping

As i know Hibernate keep track persistent object till session.close().
after session.close() the persistent object become detached object and hibernate doesn't know about this object.

i have some confusion in below two code sample.

in first code sample :- open only one session and persist a object after session.close() this object become detached and we can't perform update (e.g object.setName() ).

but in second code sample we make object detached and perform setter on object and again open a session and update this detached object.  but how this second session know the above setter value or update..

```
package objectState;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import HibernateUtils.HibernateUtils;

public class ObjectStateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();  // Transient Object
        user.setUserName("Test User");

        Session session = HibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(user);                  //Persistent Object
        user.setUserName("updated user");   //HB Keep Track Persistent Object & Perform Update if any change

        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        user.setUserName("update after session closed");  // Detached Object (HB keep track Object until session.close() )
    }

}

DetachedToPersistent.java 

    package objectState;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;

    import HibernateUtils.HibernateUtils;

    public class DetachedToPersistent {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            UserDetails user = new UserDetails();  //Transient Object
            user.setUserName("Test User");

            Session session = HibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(user);  //Persistent Object

            tx.commit();
            session.close();

            user.setUserName("update Detached User");  //Detached Object

            session = HibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.update(user);  // Persistent Detached Object

            tx.commit();
            session.close();

        }

    }
```

may be i made some mistake to understand please point out my mistake..

Thankx :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend you reading a bit about [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

1. When an object is attached, the Persistence Context detects changes using the [automatic dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/).
2. When the object becomes detached (because the Session that loaded it has closed) you can either:

   - merge the entity by calling `session.merge(entity)`, that fetches a new fresh copy and updates it with the merging entity.
   - attach the entity by calling the legacy `session.update(entity)`

The [merge method is preferred to update](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/), so use merge whenever possible.